# Container not found: goog.Disposable.instances_ error while using leak-finder-for-javascript tool

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I m using leak-finder-for-javascript tool to find memory leak in javascript.
For this m using Python 2.5 on Windows 7

```
INFO:root:Using leak definition closure-disposable
INFO:root:Reading suppressions from "closure-disposable-suppressions.txt"
INFO:root:Taking heap snapshot
INFO:root:Analyzing heap snapshot
ERROR:root:Error analyzing snapshot: <class 'leak_finder.Error'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsleakcheck.py", line 345, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "jsleakcheck.py", line 340, in main
    result = leak_checker.Run(inspector_client)
  File "jsleakcheck.py", line 151, in Run
    leaks = self._FindLeaks(client)
  File "jsleakcheck.py", line 189, in _FindLeaks
    self.leak_definition.stacktrace_suffix).FindLeaks(nodes))
  File "C:\Projects\retail\depot_tools\file\leak-finder\src\leak_finder.py", lin
e 571, in FindLeaks
    raise Error('Container not found: %s' % edge_description)
leak_finder.Error: Container not found: goog.Disposable.instances_
```

When i try to check goog.Disposable.instances_ in chrome console it shows me the object which has a leak but then it shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is discussed in the bug tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/leak-finder-for-javascript/issues/detail?id=8

Most probable reasons for this error message:

- You're inspecting a wrong page (Leak Finder always inspects the first tab; having developer tools open on that tab confuses it).
- You're trying to use the Closure leak definition with a page which doesn't use Closure.

Comment: hey marja this issue is fixed with the test page but hangs up at Taking heap snapshot for my application

Comment: and the isuue link you provide has the issue raised by me only :)